# Is there any way to apply tags to a slime after its parent was killed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever I target a slime I apply a tag to it, but as soon as it dies the tag isn't passed on. Is there anyway to pass on a tag from parent to offspring?

I'm playing Java edition.

Comment: Please put the version - is this Java or Bedrock?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to clarify, I'm playing in Java